# AndroidViewModel vs ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

With the introduction of the Android Architecture Components library, several new classes were introduced, including `AndroidViewModel` and `ViewModel`. However, I'm having trouble figuring out the difference between these two classes. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel.html) succinctly describes `AndroidViewModel` as follows:

> Application context aware `ViewModel`

I appreciate the brevity, but what exactly does this imply? When should we choose to use `AndroidViewModel` over `ViewModel` and vice-versa?

Answer (score 320, accepted):

## AndroidViewModel provides Application context

If you need to use context inside your Viewmodel you should use AndroidViewModel (AVM), because it contains the application context. To retrieve the context call `getApplication()`, otherwise use the regular ViewModel (VM).

AndroidViewModel has **application context**.
We all know *having static context instance is evil as it can cause memory leaks!!* However, **having static Application instance is not as bad as you might think** because there is only one Application instance in the running application.

Therefore, using and having Application instance in a specific class is not a problem in general. But, if an Application instance references them, it is a problem because of the reference cycle problem.

[See Also about Application Instance](https://www.philosophicalhacker.com/2015/07/14/why-static-references-to-application-contexts-are-probably-not-the-best-idea/)

## AndroidViewModel Problematic for unit tests

AVM provides application context which is problematic for unit testing. Unit tests should not deal with any of the Android lifecycle, such as context.

Comment: Why not always use AndroidViewModel then? you might later need the context even if you don't need it now. Is there any downside to that?

Comment: @T.Rex If you look at the code, it extends `ViewModel` with just a field pointing to Application. If I don't need it, I don't like having a mandatory constructor with `Application` parameter (which `AndroidViewModel` requires) and rather just use `ViewModel`. When I need a context in the future, I can easily change it then.

Comment: Use `ViewModel` when you want to use it with Fragment or to share `ViewModel` between different fragments of same Activity.

Comment: @T.Rex wouldn't using `AndroidViewModel` - being `Context`-dependent -
 make it impossible to test it in a regular unit test, leaving only instrumentation tests as a possibility? I haven't toyed with it myself (yet), it's just a thought

Comment: @KonradMorawski that sounds right. Probably not worth the trouble

Comment: When ViewModel or AndroidViewModel will be destroyed? Suppose i am executing AsyncTask in that model and i destroy app by swiping app from recent apps menu, What will happen with application context, ViewModel, AndroidViewModel and AsyncTask?

Comment: can I get the instance of simpleviewmodel through ViewModelProviders.of(this);??

Comment: So lets say I want to load data from MediaStore (Content Provider, requires Context) and I want to display that data in Fragments. I need AndroidViewModel to load but ViewModel to display?

Comment: AndroidViewModel and ViewModel  is the same, the only difference is that AndroidViewModel contains the application context.
You can use use ViewModel and to pass context to ViewModel to function that loading data from MediaStore, or use AndroidViewModel with application context.

Comment: treating context as view, breaks somehow that VM shouldn't have ref to view. In cases, when you need to do something with context, imho, it's better to create some context operation wrapper, which can be injected into the VM and called from VM. eg. `class ResController(ctx: Context) { fun getStr(id: Int) = ctx.getString(id) }` - controller can be injected, VM doesn't have ref to view(context in this case)

Answer (score 22):

Finally I got something a simpler explanation, a bit......
...The AndroidViewModel class is a subclass of ViewModel and similar to them, they are designed to store and manage UI-related data are responsible to prepare & provide data for UI and automatically allow data to survive configuration change.

The only difference with AndroidViewModel is it comes with the application context, **which is helpful if you require context to get a system service or have a similar requirement.** the bold text makes it clearer to sense it.

Comment: official source https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/locale-changes-and-the-androidviewmodel-antipattern-84eb677660d9

Comment: Doesn't the regular ViewModel have access to parent context?

Answer (score 21):

**AndroidViewModel** is subclass of **ViewModel**. The Difference between them is we can pass Application Context which can be used whenever Application Context is required for example to instantiate Database in Repository.

> **AndroidViewModel** is a Application context aware ViewModel.

**AndroidViewModel:**

```
public class PriceViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private PriceRepository priceRepository;

public PriceViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    priceRepository= new PriceRepository(application);
    allPrices = priceRepository.getAllPrices();
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class PriceViewModel extends ViewModel {
public PriceViewModel() {
    super();
}
```

> You Should use **AndroidViewModel** only when you require Application
>   Context.

You should never store a reference of activity or a view that references a activity in the ViewModel.Because ViewModel is designed to outlive a activity and it will cause Memory Leak.

Comment: Where is the `Application` value passed from?  Is it passed via constructor from another class?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Yes, it's passed by its Factory class which is abstracted away. Your starting point might be the instantiation of the vm: `by viewmodel`. See `ViewModelProvider.Factory`, [How To](https://medium.com/koderlabs/viewmodel-with-viewmodelprovider-factory-the-creator-of-viewmodel-8fabfec1aa4f). See also its source: [cs.android.com](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.kt;l=314?q=AndroidViewModelFactory)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the difference that `AndroidViewModel` gives you an `application context` whereas `ViewModel` does not. The important thing that you must understand is that `Google` itself recommends using `ViewModel` and not `AndroidViewModel`.

So, don't use `AndroidViewModel` unless it is really necessary.

See this: [GOOGLE DOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWOLm.png)

Comment: Could you provide an actual link?  A picture is usually very nice, but a screenshot is hardly a supporting argument.