# Performing network operations from ViewModel

Tags: android, android-volley, android-viewmodel

I am using ViewModel, introduced in IO/17.

I am using following guidelines provided on android developers page.
[https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html](http://Architecture%20Components%20-%20ViewModel)

Following is their sample code.

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<List<User>> users;
public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
     if (users == null) {
         users = new MutableLiveData<List<Users>>();
         loadUsers();
     }
     return users;
 }

 private void loadUsers() {
    // do async operation to fetch users
 }
}
```

I wish to perform Volley request in the '**loadUsers()**' method. But I cannot do it as it needs a '**context**' as follows

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

So my question is,

1. Is it recommended(or possible) to perform network operations inside a ViewModel??
2. If yes(if possible), how to do it?

Comment: i hv got my answer...posting late...
api calls can be made from  VM. But since i was using volley, my only concern was passing context outside view class(activity/fragment) which causes problems.
I solved this by using retrofit.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the AndroidViewModel class instead of ViewModel. AndroidViewModel holds a reference to the application context.

https://youtu.be/5qlIPTDE274

Comment: This is the right answer; also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44148966/androidviewmodel-vs-viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

Consider [Dagger](https://google.github.io/dagger/), that way you don't have to worry, about providing `context` for `Volley` from your `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

**AndroidViewModel** is subclass of **ViewModel**. The Difference between them is we can pass Application Context which can be used whenever Application Context is required for example to instantiate Database in Repository.

> **AndroidViewModel** is a Application context aware ViewModel.You must use AndroidViewModel for Application Context.

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<List<User>> users;
private Application application;
public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    this.application=application;
    super(application);
}
public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers() {
    if (users == null) {
        users = new MutableLiveData<List<Users>>();
        loadUsers();
    }
    return users;
}

private void loadUsers() {
    // Pass Context to Repository
}}
```

You should **never store a reference of activity or a view** that references a activity in the ViewModel.Because ViewModel is designed to outlive a activity and it will cause Memory Leak.

> Is it recommended(or possible) to perform network operations inside a
>   ViewModel??

No, you should not perform Networking Operations inside a ViewModel.

> If yes(if possible), how to do it?

Get Application Context by using AndroidModelView and pass it to Repository,
as recommended by Android Team.

[image]