# trying to access resources through viewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-resources

I am trying to access a string indicating an API key from Resources through my viewModel class `mapViewModel` by having an application class named `AppUtils` with the method `getKey()` which returns the string resource.

*I **do not** want to pass any context/activity to the viewModel in order to keep the code around the MVVM architecture
:

```
class AppUtils : Application() {

    fun getKey() = resources.getString(R.string.google_maps_key)
 }
```

viewModel:

```
class MapViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val appKey = AppUtils().getKey()
```

when running the project i get an error saying that the resources object i am referring to is null

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

any suggestions?
Thanks !

Comment: Just use AndroidViewModel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44148966/androidviewmodel-vs-viewmodel

Comment: lol its a little funny because AndroidViewModel requires an application in its constructor so.. of course i will have access to the application xD but how do i initialize in activity an AndroidViewModel and pass an application to its constructor?

Comment: same way you obtain a normal viewmodel, default factory recognizes AVM and fills in the application argument for you