# Unable to use getApplicationContext in viewModel android

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

New to android and trying to implement MVVM

I am trying to use getApplicationContext in ViewModel while using cursor .
I think context is not available in ViewModel , then how should i use cursor.

I am building application to access all folder having videos in it .[image]

Comment: make your `ViewModel` extends `AndroidViewModel` check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44148966/androidviewmodel-vs-viewmodel

Comment: actually, it's better to avoid androidContext in your ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get access to `ApplicationContext` inside you `ViewModel` make sure that your viewModel class extends `AndroidViewModel`, so you can get the `ApplicationContext` by calling `getApplication()` method :

```
class FolderViewModel  extends AndroidViewModel {

    public FolderViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        getApplication();
    }
    ...
```

Comment: can u tell me how to create instance of this viewmodel

Comment: `FolderViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(FolderViewModel.class);`

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.xparticle.divplayer/in.xparticle.divplayer.HomeActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class in.xparticle.divplayer.viewmodels.FolderViewModel   gettting this error need help

Answer (score 0):

Here is step-by-step how to use the application context from ViewModel.

**Step 1:** Let your class extends AndroidViewModel

```
public class FolderViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public FolderViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public void getAllFolders() {
        Cursor cursor = getApplication().getContentResolver()
                .query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Create a viewmodel instance from your activity

```
ViewModelProvider.Factory factory = 
        ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(getApplication());
ViewModelProvider provider = new ViewModelProvider(this, factory);
FolderViewModel folderViewModel = provider.get(FolderViewModel.class);

// Call methods of viewmodel
folderViewModel.getAllFolders();
```