# How to maintain multiple independent states where each state can be read and written by multiple pages in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a screen showing a list of independent input forms (namely "the first screen"). For each of them, it is a composable consists of multiple fields. Clicking a field would redirect users to nested children screens, for example, for autocomplete, multi-select options or date picker, to let user modify that field. The children screen may redirect users to deeper children screens. After modification is done, user would back to the first screen and the field display would be updated accordingly.

[Illustration of Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBdSb.png)

In SwiftUI, it can be implemented so easily that, the first screen owns states of all the forms, where each form can be implemented as a View component, owning states of all the fields of that form. The states of each form are propagated to and modified by subsequent screens using `@Binding`.

In Android Jetpack Compose, there is no equivalent to `@Binding`. The most similar concept here would be callbacks, but callbacks cannot be passed over different screens. In Android Navigation Compose, the states of the first screen are destroyed as soon as users moving to another screen. Backstack saved state bundle cannot be applied directly, because the depth of children pages can be more than one, and there are multiple forms sharing the same backstack entry. Creating a `ViewModel` associating to the navigation is also not an option due to the same reason.

Without modifying the model layer to associate each form to some unique IDs or adding repositories, how to maintain all these states properly and simply?

Comment: Adding veiwModel for the the different views that shares a single repo or a single shared veiwModel to start is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

can use [AndroidViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel)

It should be that AndroidViewModel inherits from ViewModel, for more explanation, you can also refer to
[This explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44148966/androidviewmodel-vs-viewmodel)

And this [Medium's blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/locale-changes-and-the-androidviewmodel-antipattern-84eb677660d9)